# Hibernate Query problem with Informix

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, seam, informix

I have written an application using Seam 2.2.1 & MySQL which is working. I am now trying to connect the application to **Informix** and when I execute a query from **hibernate**(`select user from User user`) I am getting the following exceptions:

> org.hibernate.exception.genericjdbcexception could not execute query

when i execute a query as `select user.id,user.name from User user` it's executed successefuly.

The Generated sql is

> select
>           first 2 user0_.USER_ID as USER1_120_,
>           user0_.dateOfBirth as dateOfBi2_120_,
>           user0_.enabled as enabled120_,
>           user0_.forename as forename120_,
>           user0_.password as password120_,
>           user0_.surname as surname120_,
>           user0_.userName as userName120_ 
>       from
>           anetidb.user user0_ 
>       where
>           username=?

The Stacktrace of exception:

> 12:00:24,407 INFO  [IntegerType] could not read column value from result set: USER1_120_; No such column name
>   12:00:24,665 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: -79738, SQLState: IX000
>   12:00:24,873 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] No such column name

And i Use org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect as hibernate.dialect

Have you an idea about the problem?

Thks For Help.

Comment: Have you sepecified the appropriate dialect? What's the stack trace of the exception? What's the generated SQL?

Comment: The Stacktrace of exception:

    12:00:24,407 INFO [IntegerType] could not read column value from result set: USER1_120_; No such column name 12:00:24,665 WARN [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: -79738, SQLState: IX000 12:00:24,873 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] No such column name

And i Use org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect as hibernate.dialect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Googling for `"No such column name" informix hibernate` has led me to the following Hibernate bug report, which describes exactly the same problem: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HBX-1126

The solution seems to remove the parameter DELIMIDENT=y from the datasource URL.

Comment: Anis, marking this answer as accepted would be the social stackoverflow way to show your gratitude

Answer (score -1):

You meant this query:

```
FROM User
```

Because the select tag in HQL doesn't have to be specified when you want to retrieve all the properties of the object.

Comment: From User 
return the same exception also, there is no difference, i don't understand how to retrieve all the propreties of objects with informix and hibernate.

Comment: He says he is using JPA, and in JPQL the "SELECT user" is MANDATORY FOR PORTABLE CODE.