# Informix Hibernate Query

Tags: hibernate

it seems that I have similar problem like this one [Hibernate Query problem with Informix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444426/hibernate-query-problem-with-informix) or at less I have the same exception. I use hibernate 3.6.6, jboss 6.1 and informix10. Infact everything worked fine before migration, when jboss 5 was used. Also I want to mention I dont have parameter `DELIMIDENT` in my url.

My problem comes on the class which has two embedded field (for clarity : the names are as follow, sender and cerrier) with the same reference type. Both of the field use `@AttributeOverride` and `@AssociationOverride` to override properly names of the columns and association of the class which is annotated with `@embeddable`. The last one also have `@OneToOne` relationship with other entity. I try to check which on of the field make the problem so everything begins to work fine if I delete "sender" field. Here is a part of the code:

```
@Embeddable
public class ProductsAgent{ @Column(name = "name") private String name; @Column(name = "statute") private String statute; @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) @JoinColumn(name = "products_agent_address_id") private Address address; }
@Entity
class Registration76v{
@Embedded
@AssociationOverride(name = "address", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sender_address_id", table = "registration76v"))
@AttributeOverrides(value = { @AttributeOverride(name = "name", column = @Column(name = "sender_name", table = "registration76v")), @AttributeOverride(name = "statute", column = @Column(name = "sender_statute", table = "registration76v")) })
private ProductsAgent1 sender = new ProductsAgent1();
@Embedded
@AssociationOverride(name = "address", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "carrier_address_id", table = "registration76v"))
@AttributeOverrides(value = { @AttributeOverride(name = "name", column = @Column(name = "carrier_name", table = "registration76v")), @AttributeOverride(name = "statute", column = @Column(name = "carrier_statute", table = "registration76v")) })
private ProductsAgent carrier = new ProductsAgent();
}
```

here is a part of the log:

```
16:20:38,212 WARN [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: -79738, SQLState: IX000
16:20:38,212 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] No such column name
16:20:38,215 INFO [org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener] Error performing load command: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity:
16:20:38,215 INFO [org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener] Error performing load command: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity:
```

Somehow my colleague find that the problem comes from wrong generated code here sql. And to be more specif with generated alias of `sender_address_id` by which the given column is searched later.
So, if someone can give me a advice how to solve this problem I really will appreciate that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What database version used before migration?

Comment: the same. informix 10