# ERROR: No such column name.INFO: HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException:

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, informix

I just created a simple Java project. I am able to persist the object successfully, but when I try to retrieve it, it throws an error:

> ERROR: No such column name
>   Jan 02, 2016 5:44:05 PM org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener onLoad
>   INFO: HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[org.neeraj.walmart.dto.UserDetails#1]

My code for Entity class is :

```
package org.neeraj.walmart.dto;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
public class UserDetails {
    @Id
    private int userNewid;
    private String userName;

    private Date joinedDate;
    private String Address;
    private String description;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userNewid;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userNewid = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public Date getJoinedDate() {
        return joinedDate;
    }
    public void setJoinedDate(Date joinedDate) {
        this.joinedDate = joinedDate;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Test class for testing hibernate is:

```
package org.neeraj.walmart;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.RollbackException;

import org.neeraj.walmart.dto.UserDetails;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserDetails user1 = new UserDetails();
        user1.setUserId(1);
        user1.setUserName("First User");
        user1.setJoinedDate(new Date());
        user1.setAddress("User1 address");
        user1.setDescription("User1 description is present here");


        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HibernateLearningContext");
        //Code snippet to save the object to DB
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(user1);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (RollbackException ex) {
           em.getTransaction().rollback();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }

        // code snippet to retrieve the object
        UserDetails user1Copy = null;
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        user1Copy = em.find(UserDetails.class, 1); // This method finds by primary key
        if (user1Copy == null) {
            System.out.println(" data not found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("user name retrived is " + user1Copy.getUserName());
        }

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

DDL which is being used to create the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE userdetails (
    userNewid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(255),
    description VARCHAR(255),
    joineddate DATETIME,
    username VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT u177_235 PRIMARY KEY (userNewid)
);
```

[image: Stack Trace for error in eclipse console]

Comment: what's your table like?

Comment: Table DDL looks like this :-    CREATE TABLE outbound:gls.user_details (
 userNewid INTEGER NOT NULL,
 address VARCHAR(255),
 description VARCHAR(255),
 joineddate DATE,
 username VARCHAR(255),
 CONSTRAINT u160_201 PRIMARY KEY (userNewid)
); this i copied from Dbeaver DDL

Comment: @SMA is this table structure you were looking or something else?

Comment: well your class implies columns names like "userName", "joinedDate" and you don't have those. Doing a basic schema validation would tell you that ... assuming your JPA implementation offers that feature.

Comment: @Neil if you see my above comment where i specified whole DDL which i extracted from DBeaver, it shows every column which is present in my class. Note:- Tables is being created successfully and data also being persisted. Problem occurs when i am doing find on entity manager

Comment: I can see the DDL (which you should put in the QUESTION, not a COMMENT, and whatever this DBeaver thing is, it doesn't understand JPA). As I already said, you don't have the columns I said ... you have different CASE. Also you should update your question to include the FULL EXCEPTION + stack trace

Comment: @Neil, i have added the stack trace and ddl in comments. please help if you can

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444426/hibernate-query-problem-with-informix

Comment: Please tell us WHERE is the STACK TRACE of this EXCEPTION? It is NOT in the post or in that image

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer - but anyway ADDRESS is a reserved word for IBM Informix - consider changing the column name as well. See [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1818.htm).

Comment: @Neil . last 3-4 line of image states about the error related to load command. Did not get any exception. My mistake, I spelled the wrong word as exception.

Comment: "did not get any exception" ? Really ... apart from org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[org.neeraj.walmart.dto.UserDetails#1] so why not just print out the stack trace?!!

Comment: link suggested by @RC solved my problem. it was some bug in hibernate with respect to informix query. Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate has this [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HBX-1126) which is similar to your problem.

Remove parameter DELIMIDENT=y from the datasource URL.

Generally `HHH000327` this error comes when you have some error in naming column in tables. So you can try to name columns with `@Column` annotation. Be sure that you are not using any database specific constant , like `User` is already defined constant in postgres.